# Use a custom font inside pstricks environment

Tags: fonts, pdftex, luatex, pstricks

I have converted svg-icons of car brands into a custom font because the pstricks macro can only take alphanumeric characters in the text-argument and not images (I have the icons in svg, eps and png format).

How can I use this custom font inside a pstricks environment where I must use pdftex (in my case LaTeX)?

Is it possible?

This is what my font look like when the font is installed on my local computer and I must use LuaLaTeX (not pdftex) to compile:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fontspec}  % requires XeLaTex or LuaLaTeX
\newfontfamily\customfont[]{untitled-font-1}

\begin{document}
   {\huge \customfont a} {\huge \customfont b} {\huge \customfont c} {\huge \customfont d}  
   {\huge \customfont e} {\huge \customfont f} {\huge \customfont g} {\huge \customfont h} 
   {\huge \customfont i} {\huge \customfont \%} {\huge \customfont !} 
\end{document}
```

The result is:
[image: The custom car-font]

I want to use this font of car brands inside the pstricks environment - but then I have to use normal LaTeX (pdftex) to compile, but then the following code will not work because the font require LuaLaTeX:

```
% added this packages to preamble 
\usepackage{lmodern}  
\usepackage{multido} 
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-text}

% body
\DeclareFixedFont{\SF}{T1}{phv}{b}{n}{2.45cm}
\pstextpath(0,-0.3ex){\pscharpath*[linestyle=none]{\SF Cars}}{\tiny \multido{}{202}{%
   {\huge \customfont a} {\huge \customfont b} {\huge \customfont c} {\huge \customfont d}  
   {\huge \customfont e} {\huge \customfont f} {\huge \customfont g} {\huge \customfont h} 
   {\huge \customfont i} {\huge \customfont \%} {\huge \customfont !}  }}
```

This is how the result looks like with fontawesome icons (but I want to use the car brand icons :( ...):

[image]

**The problem summarized: the custom font demands LuaLatex while pstricks demands LaTeX. How can I solve this issue?**

**Edit: when I use the XeLaTex engine:**
This is the error-message I get when I use the XeLaTeX engine on overleaf.com:
[image]

And this is the result:
[image]

I.e XeLaTex does not like the pstextpath and the pscharpath macros. Hope that can help. I can also supply different kind of log files if someone wants to take a look.

Comment: Can't you use `xelatex`? Or maybe with the recent package  `auto-pst-pdf-lua`?

Comment: @Bernard I don´t think XeLaTeX is compatible with pstricks.

Comment: I don't think the auto-pst-pdf-lua package will help in this case because that package seems to convert pstricks stuff into images that is inserted in the pdf in the second run. My custom-font will be part of the image, but they is not defined in the first run.

Comment: If there are fewer than 256 icons in the font, could you encode it as a Type 1 font with the `U` encoding?

Comment: For auto-pst-pdf-lua, it was only a suggestion (I don't use lualatex). As to XeLaTeX, I'm sorry, but all my answers on this site using pstricks were compiled with it.

Comment: @Davislor It is 81 icons in total. Type 1 font is os-dependent and comes with many files. How would I proceed if I can convert it? How do I declare them and use them?

Comment: @Mr.B A very simplified sketch of an answer that hides a lot of frustrating detail is: you should be able to save it in the format other 8-bit TeX fonts use from FontForge, and then install them with `fontinst`. If at all possible, I’d recommend you compile with LuaTeX.

Comment: But you might find it easier to convert the SVG icons to standalone mini-PDFs and include them with `\graphicx`, or convert their control points to a TikZ drawing, or use the `svg` package. Doing this by saving as a font and loading with pstricks might not be the best approach.

Comment: It should, though, be possible for PDFTeX to read a `.ttf` file.

Comment: `pst-text`  is not supported by `xdvipdfmx`. You have always to use `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf`. However, it is easy to create a Type 1 font version with `fontinst`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puuh - not easy, but very nice:

[image: The word car outlined with car brands icons]

I use TeX Live, TexMaker and FontForge that runs on OS X machine.

So this is what I did:

**I converted the .svg files into a postscript font (in other words a .pfb and .afm file):**

1. Used FontForge to import the svg-images and to generate the font (PS Type 1 binary - has fileextension `.pfb`). The car icons is mapped to 0-9A-Za-e.

[image: FontForge]

**Get LaTeX to use the car-font locally:**

1. Made a directory - that I called `testfont` that I put the `cars___.afm` and `cars___.pfb` files into.
2. Run the commandoline tool and set the working directory to testfont: `cd testfont`.
3. Used TEX utilities to produce the `.map` file and the `.pl` file (human readable):

   ```
   afm2pl -p texnansi cars___.afm cars8y.pl
   ```
4. Then I used the `.pl` file to get the `.tfm` file (compact binary file):

   ```
   pltotf cars8y
   ```
5. Made the `.fd` file that I called `ly1mycarfontfam.fd` that is saved to the testfont folder with this content:

   ```
   \ProvidesFile{ly1mycarfontfam.fd}
   \DeclareFontFamily{LY1}{mycarfontfam}{} 
   \DeclareFontShape{LY1}{mycarfontfam}{m}{n}{<-> cars8y }{}
   ```
6. And the content in `testfont.tex` file:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \pagestyle{empty}

   % Car font
   \usepackage{texnansi}
   % I cannot use the \pdfmacro when I use LaTeX -> dvips -> ps2pdf
   %\pdfmapfile{=cars8y.map}
   \newcommand{\fancyfont}%
   {\fontfamily{mycarfontfam}\selectfont}

   % Pstricks
   \usepackage{pst-plot}
   \usepackage{pst-text}

   \begin{document}
   \DeclareFixedFont{\SF}{T1}{phv}{b}{n}{3.5cm}

   \hspace*{-1.5cm}\pstextpath(0,-0.5ex){\pscharpath*[linestyle=none]{\SF Cars}}{
   \scriptsize \multido{}{120}{\fancyfont 345678HIJLMNRSXYZ}
   }
   \end{document}
   ```
7. Result:

[image: Result before dvips]

11. Not good. This is because I cannot use \pdfmapfile macro in dvips mode. So when you have compiled the tex-code you also get an `testfont.dvi` file in the directory, and you have to use the commandoline with the following commando each time where you supply the name of the map- and dvi- file (this will update the `testfont.ps` file):

    ```
    dvips -u +cars8y.map testfont.dvi
    ```

Double-click the `testfont.ps` file in the folder and a copy gets made in `.pdf` format with the result shown above or use the following commando to update the `.pdf` file from the updated `.ps` file: `ps2pdfwr testfont.ps testfont.pdf`

Isn´t it nice (with some dummy text)?

[image: Sweety cars]